# DataTables, serverSide and pagination on Django

Tags: django, datatables, pagination, server-side

I use DataTables with [serverSide render](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "{% url 'core:persons_json' %}",
        "columns": [
          {"data": "full_name"},
          {"data": "email"},
        ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

In my views.py i have:

```
def persons_json(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    data = [item.to_dict_json() for item in persons]
    page = 1
    per_page = 10
    res = {
        'data': data,
        'page': page,
        'per_page': per_page,
        'total': math.ceil(persons.count() / per_page)
    }
    return JsonResponse(res)
```

But still he still returns all the persons. And I want to avoid loading a lot of data.

But when i define, for example:

```
def persons_json(request):
    length = int(request.GET.get('length'))
    persons = Person.objects.all()[:length]
    data = [item.to_dict_json() for item in persons]
    page = 1
    per_page = 10
    res = {
        'data': data,
        'page': page,
        'per_page': per_page,
        'total': math.ceil(persons.count() / per_page)
    }
    return JsonResponse(res)
```

`length = int(request.GET.get('length'))` is parameter send by serverSide:

```
http://localhost:8000/person/json/?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=full_name&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=email&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1568072064631
```

Note that we have: `start=0&length=10`.

**My question** is as follows: when I use this second option. The pagination of other items does not appear in DataTables, ie

I wanted it here

[image]

*but only one page appears.*

Does anyone know how I do to return all pages, and I go clicking each to advance the pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve. DataTable send start and length. And API need return recordsTotal and recordsFiltered.

https://github.com/rg3915/django-datatables-experiment/issues/1